# Convert LUIS Datetime V2 to JS Date

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, botframework, azure-language-understanding

Is there a builtin helper method in LUIS Sdk or Bot Sdk to convert the LUIS DatetimeV2 entities to JS Date objects? I have seen some have been using Chronic Parser for C# but I couldn't find anything that works for Nodejs.

```
const dt = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(args.intent.entities, 'datetimeV2');
if (dt) {
    // this is just the matching intent, I believe.
    // example intents; today, yesterday, 2/28, 31/5, ...
    // How do I convert this to a valid Date is where I am stuck.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract `datetimeV2` entities in NodeJS, it is more specific in that you'll need to run:

```
const dt = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(args.intent.entities,
    'builtin.datetimeV2.date'); 

const dt_daterange = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(args.intent.entities, 
    'builtin.datetimeV2.daterange');
```

To create a Date object you can look it up here at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Several_ways_to_create_a_Date_object).

Here's a [blogpost](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/05/08/Luis-Date-Time-Entities/) on datetimeV2 that shows the entity's structure in the LUIS response object.

To create a Date object, you can take `dt.resolution.values[i]['value']` and place it into a constructor like so:

```
const dt_obj = new Date(dt.resolution.values[i]['value']);
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know there's `resolution` property in the `IEntity` type. Just saw it when `stringify`ing the entire `dt` object. This works like a charm!

Comment: Thank you! This answer helped me a lot.. in my case I am only getting the first value, so I did like this:  `start_date = new Date(builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(intent.entities, 'builtin.datetimeV2.daterange').resolution.values[0].start);`